# Windows Phone 8 How to put element above Page Panorama?

Tags: windows-phone-8

here is my issue :

I am develloping an application where there is a Walkthrought, to make it I used Page Panorama, the problem is that I need to keep an element (button) completly still while the user can navigate throught the Panorama.

P.S.: I am beginnier in Windows phone, so if the answer appears obvious for other, I'll be glad to have a clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your layout, but using a grid is likely the best solution:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Hello world!" />

    <Panorama Grid.Row="1"></Panorama>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I just had to remouve the line :
    <Panorama Grid.Row="1"></Panorama>
To have requested behavior, thanks